# Default sharepoint cancel button

Tags: button, sharepoint-2010

I have a web part that for new and edit functionality for custom list.

I need a cancel button on it same as

```
    <SharePoint:SaveButton />
```

tag outputs the default save button in sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.gobackbutton.aspx

```
<SharePoint:GoBackButton />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that cancel button only redirects to another page, so you can create your own button and handle click event in code behind (ASP.NET) or with JS - if you don't have access to code behind (i.e. in SharePoint Designer).

If there's "Source" argument in URL, then you must take destination URL from it. Otherwise you should probably redirect to current list URL or sth.

//EDIT: I don't know if there exists default cancel button tag or something similar ;)